# How to Measure data consumed by an user in Azure sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, users, monitoring, azure-sql-managed-instance

For an Azure sql server MI, we have multiple external users consuming data,
I would like to know how much data an user is consuming/extracting from the DB?

Can this be checked from,
1.) From SSMS using queries or UI?
2.) Azure portal?

Comment: Have you looked at [sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-io-virtual-file-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? [Here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/10/t-sql-queries/io-latency) is a detail write up by Erin Stellato.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide  I guess the number of reads and number of writes would do good, but 'sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats' provides on the whole at DB level.
Can we get this for each user for a particular DB?
example, Num_of_reads by 'user1' in a DB.  Btw, Thank you for the response.

Comment: I have not tested this myself. I suggest these two extended events (and maybe there are others), `sqlserver.file_read` and `sqlserver.file_write_completed` in combination with actions (to filter by username) will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide  Does this require us to create an extended event task? Or is it kind of a default option or something?

Comment: You will need to create an extended event trace, save the data a sql server table, do  some aggregation to get the data you are looking for. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: @SqlWorlWide let me try them out, thank you for your inputs.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I have tried it and could not get it with the mentioned events,  Have summarized in this question. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237275/how-to-know-the-size-of-data-returned-from-a-select-statement-using-extended-eve